# .NET - How to force an assembly digital certificate validation when referenced from another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, security, digital-signature, strongname

I have an executable(.exe) which references an assembly(.dll). I have signed the dll with a self signed certificate.

For generating the cerificate I used the makecert tool to create a custom authority, then created a client certificate signed by that authority following this post:
http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development

After that signed the dll agaisnt the pfx file using the signtool.exe.

When I right click on the dll I can see the "Digital Signatures" tab, check the details of the certificate and confirm that it is valid on my machine as I have added the custom root authority to the Trusted Authorities store.

The dll is copied in the bin/debug dir of the exe.

My main goal is to assure that the dll which is referenced from the exe is the valid one which we have certified. It has the proper vendor, version and so on.

I have tried to strong-name the dll and it worked fine. The problem is that strong-naming is more of a version integrity solution instead of a real security measure.

My questions is: How can I force the exe to always check the dll's certificate so that if the dll has been tampered I would get a runtime error explaining that the publisher is invalid or something similar.

Comment: Why won't strongnaming work for you?  If it's been tampered with, the strongname will be different, so the exe won't work.  If an attacker has enough access to change/rebuild the exe against the tampered with dll, they've got enough access to remove the checks for the valid cert from your exe too

Comment: Right, the thing is that I could find many examples of removing the strong name validation using ildasm, ilasm and any time of hex editor. I couldn't find such when using certificates so I thought it's impossible the same to be achieved so easily. Are you sure that having the exe and the dll they can both be malformed to work together with an "evil" code even when using digital signatures? Is there any source which can prove that?

Comment: A signature just proves to an end user of the source of the file.  It doesn't prevent it from being decompiled, changed and recompiled etc.  Your end users (using windows) would be able to inspect the certificate, but if someone has access to both the exe and dll, they can both be changed

Comment: Thanks Jeams, this makes sense. Just from curiosity - strong-naming validates only against the public key. What if I also want to validate the vendor of the dll? Are the certificates used only for a manual end user check whether the downloaded code is trusted? You've been very helpful with your suggestions but I didn't get an answer if it's possible to somehow automatically check the certificate also in the same manner as the strong-name public key?

Comment: I'm sure there probably is a way to check/validate the signing certificate, I've never done so though.  My point was, if someone has access to change the dll, they (probably) also have access to change the exe - they can change/remove the certificate checking code too, which is why I'm not sure it gives you any more protection than strong naming would.  What they couldn't do is re-sign it with a certificate purporting to be from you (assuming at some point you get a signing cert from a globally trusted root CA), but if your users aren't looking, they won't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Strong naming should not be used for integrity checking. The .NET assembly loader does not validate the integrity of strong name assemblies anymore (since .NET 3.5 SP1).

However, you can turn this feature back on through configuration. If you want to prevent assemblies from being modified on disk, you should use [Authenticode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750035.aspx).

This [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/05/14/strong-name-bypass.aspx) article and this [blog](http://www.outercurve.org/blog/2014/03/25/Strongnaming-I-Do-Not-Think-It-Means-What-You-Thin/) article describe the changesin more depth.

Comment: OK but when I tried the following: 1.Strong name the dll 2.Reference it from the exe 3.Build another dll without strong name and override the old one 4.Run the exe 5.An exception was thrown that the manifest does not match. This was the behabiour I was expecting. The strong name was checked and captured that the dll is malformed. Can you plese clarify?